# Linq to Entities: How to pass a parameter to a string Contains method within a join?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Basically, this works:

```
from membershipUser in context.MembershipUsers
join user in context.Users on membershipUser.UserName equals (user.UserName.Contains("partner:") ? user.UserName.Replace("partner:", "") : user.UserName)
```

But this doesn't:

```
var usernamePrefix = "partner:";
...
from membershipUser in context.MembershipUsers
join user in context.Users on membershipUser.UserName equals (user.UserName.Contains(usernamePrefix) ? user.UserName.Replace(usernamePrefix, "") : user.UserName
```

I keep getting a timeout exception.

The only difference in the generated SQL scripts is that the first one renders:

```
LIKE N'%partner:%'
```

While the latter renders:

```
LIKE '%partner:%' /* @p__linq__3 */ ESCAPE N'~'
```

(Both SQL scripts work when run in the Management Studio)

Any thoughts?

(UPDATE: I've seen that with a small number of rows both ways work, but when I hit more than 1000 rows I get the timeout exception)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you declare `usernamePrefix` as a `const string`?

Comment: Declaring it as a constant makes it work, but I need to change that value in runtime.

Comment: what is the column type?

Comment: It seems to me that u want to check if the `UserName` starts with a curtain string or not, have to tried to user `StartsWith` instead on `Contains`

Comment: The column type is VARCHAR, StartsWith doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

L2E always uses a SQL param with non-constant values for security against SQL injection attacks.

As you've seen, however, the DB server can't always optimize parameterized queries as well.

However, Entity SQL has no such restriction, so you can write an ESQL query.

Alternately, map a proc, view, or use ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand.

You can also change the DB schema to store a directly compare-able value.

By the way, [I consider mapping the ASP.NET membership tables to be a bad idea.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)

Edit: One more thing to try...

```
from membershipUser in context.MembershipUsers
from user in context.Users
where membershipUser.UserName == user.UserName
     || membershipUser.UserName == usernamePrefix + user.UserName
select ...
```

Comment: Sure but what's funny is that it only fails with a large amount of data. I guess I'll have to use a proc then.

Comment: It's not so strange. You're doing, essentially, a cross-product on a non-indexable function. But try the LINQ in my edit; it should give the same results, and the server *might* be able to index it.

Comment: The LINQ in your edit doesn't work, the resulting CROSS JOIN just kills the server. (But thanks anyway!)